# Grid Fill not working

Tags: modeling

I have a selection of vertices that I want to bridge. I would like to use the grid fill tool because there are vertices in between. I am however getting an error *Edge Loop Vertex mismatch*

[image]

Comment: Can you upload your blend? :)

Comment: @ThomBlairIII I already fixed it manually. I thinks this shape should be easy enough to re-create

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an incorrect use of the tool, not an issue with the tool itself.

Comment: @CharlesLyes I know, I closed voted it myself. Not sure if that or deleting it is the appropriate action

Comment: I get a "Connecting edges vertex mismatch" error if I rip a vertex at the side and leave it in place, that is one of the un-selected verts on the side is actually two disconnected verts. In fact the unconnected faces drawn at each corner would indicate you have disconnected duplicates at each corner.

Answer (score 3):

### **"Edge loop vertex count mismatch" Error**

"Edge loop vertex count mismatch" error occurs when the number of selected vertices of the two edges you want to use Grid Fill on are not equal, as seen here:

[image]

So, maybe you have a vertex selected on one side that's not selected on the other side.

Comment: I know why I am getting the error - _ -. But in my case they match up.

Comment: Maybe you have a hidden duplicate vertex?

Comment: Hmm I don't know anymore